# Why does pthread_create() returns 0 but the thread never starts

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am coming from a Java background and am comfortable using Java's synchronization for multi threaded programming. Recently, I started to dabble in C++ and have had to work on some multi-threaded code. Following is the smallest working example of the issue that I am facing.

```
class TxStatus {
    private:
        int numOperations;
        bool commitStatus;
        pthread_mutex_t statusLock;

    public:
        TxStatus() {
            this->commitStatus = false;
            this->numOperations = 0;
        }
        void addNewOperation() {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&statusLock);
            numOperations++;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&statusLock);
        }
        void operationCompleted() {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&statusLock);
            numOperations--;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&statusLock);
        }
        void commit() {
            this->commitStatus = true;
        }

};

class TxManager {
    private:
        unsigned long long globalFrontier;
        unsigned long long txId;

        pthread_mutex_t gfLock;
        pthread_mutex_t txIdLock;

        std::map<unsigned long long, TxStatus> txStatusMap;

    public:
        TxManager() {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&gfLock);
            globalFrontier = 1;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&gfLock);

            pthread_mutex_lock(&txIdLock);
            txId = 1;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&txIdLock);
        }

        unsigned long long beginNewTx() {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&txIdLock);
            unsigned long long newId = txId;
            txId++;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&txIdLock);
            TxStatus statusObj;
            txStatusMap.insert(std::make_pair(newId,statusObj));
            return newId;
        }

        void addUnflushedOperation(unsigned long long txId) {
            txStatusMap[txId].addNewOperation();
        }
        void markOperationAsFlushed(unsigned long long txId) {
            txStatusMap[txId].operationCompleted();
        }
        void markCommitted(unsigned long long txId) {
            txStatusMap[txId].commit();
        }
};


void * thread( void *args){

    TxManager txManager;
    fprintf(stderr,"Inside thread");
    unsigned long long newTxId = txManager.beginNewTx();

    fprintf(stderr,"Tx Started: %d", newTxId );
    txManager.addUnflushedOperation(newTxId);
    pthread_exit(NULL);   

}

int main(){
    pthread_t tx_thread;
    fprintf(stderr,"Inside main");
    int ret = pthread_create(&tx_thread, NULL, thread, NULL);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error launching thread");
    }else{
        fprintf(stderr,"Thread launched successfully");
    }


    if (pthread_join(tx_thread, NULL) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Join pthread failed");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

The thread is launched successfully but I never see one of the prints from the functions executed in the thread itself i.e thread(). If I remove the join call then the program just terminates after printing the statements inside the main method.

Comment: From what I can see you don't initialize your mutex, you are locking things that don't need locking and failing to lock things that do. Do you have access to `C++11` and `std::thread`?

Comment: @Galik could you please elaborate on what you mean when you say "you are locking things that don't need locking and failing to lock things that do"?

Comment: For example in `beginNewTx()` you lock access to `txId` suggesting that this function will be called from multiple threads but you do not lock access to `txStatusMap` which needs locking if modified from more than one thread.

Comment: Also, in your constructor for `TxManager` you lock access when you initialize its members but it is not possible for more than one thread to create the same object so you do not need to lock access to its members during constructor initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pthreads is a C library. Its data types are dumb C types. If you just place them in a class or struct, they won't get auto-initialized. You need to initialize them.
The easiest way to do it is with `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` (alternatively with `pthread_mutex_init`) which in C++, you can do right next to the member declaration.

This doesn't hang:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <map>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
class TxStatus {
    private:
        int numOperations;
        bool commitStatus;
        pthread_mutex_t statusLock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

    public:
        TxStatus() {
            this->commitStatus = false;
            this->numOperations = 0;
        }
        void addNewOperation() {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&statusLock);
            numOperations++;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&statusLock);
        }
        void operationCompleted() {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&statusLock);
            numOperations--;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&statusLock);
        }
        void commit() {
            this->commitStatus = true;
        }

};

class TxManager {
    private:
        unsigned long long globalFrontier;
        unsigned long long txId;

        pthread_mutex_t gfLock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
        pthread_mutex_t txIdLock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

        std::map<unsigned long long, TxStatus> txStatusMap;

    public:
        TxManager() {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&gfLock);
            globalFrontier = 1;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&gfLock);

            pthread_mutex_lock(&txIdLock);
            txId = 1;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&txIdLock);
        }

        unsigned long long beginNewTx() {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&txIdLock);
            unsigned long long newId = txId;
            txId++;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&txIdLock);
            TxStatus statusObj;
            txStatusMap.insert(std::make_pair(newId,statusObj));
            return newId;
        }

        void addUnflushedOperation(unsigned long long txId) {
            txStatusMap[txId].addNewOperation();
        }
        void markOperationAsFlushed(unsigned long long txId) {
            txStatusMap[txId].operationCompleted();
        }
        void markCommitted(unsigned long long txId) {
            txStatusMap[txId].commit();
        }
};


void * thread( void *args){

    TxManager txManager;
    fprintf(stderr,"Inside thread\n");
    unsigned long long newTxId = txManager.beginNewTx();

    fprintf(stderr,"Tx Started: %llu", newTxId );
    txManager.addUnflushedOperation(newTxId);
    pthread_exit(NULL);   

}

int main(){
    pthread_t tx_thread;
    fprintf(stderr,"Inside main\n");
    int ret = pthread_create(&tx_thread, NULL, thread, NULL);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error launching thread");
    }else{
        fprintf(stderr,"Thread launched successfully");
    }


    if (pthread_join(tx_thread, NULL) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Join pthread failed");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

You appear to be missing a call to [pthread_mutex_init](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_init) in your constructors.  That might be part of the problem.

The other issue is that your fprintf statements need to have a newline.

That is, this line:

```
fprintf(stderr,"Inside thread");
```

Updated to this:

```
fprintf(stderr,"Inside thread\n");
```

The `\n` char will flush the output buffers such that your messages actually appear on the screen.

Apply similar treatment for the other print statements.

Also, you appear to be using a different lock per variable. Consider just having one single mutex instance. And you may not need a lock in TxStatus either....